# Update dependencies in Project B when Project A is released

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have two multi module projects. One is the main project tree. The other project tree pulls in the artifacts (WARs, JARs, etc) from the first project.  They each have their own separate parent pom.

I would like to keep their version numbers identical.  Project 2 has a dependency management section that has the artifacts from project 1 in it. The problem with this is that I can't release the project due to snapshots.

For example.  The version number (for both projects) is 3.4-SNAPSHOT.  I can release a version 3.4 of project 1 and all the pom versions will be set from 3.4-SNAPSHOT to 3.5. When I go into project 2, I want to do the same exact thing. The hitch is that dependencies of project 1 are at 3.4-SNAPSHOT and I can't figure out how to automatically get them to be 3.5.  It's like I want the dependencies to be updated to the release version, before actually releasing.

I understand that if I make both trees extend from the same parent pom, the maven release plugin would detect the dependencies as submodules and update them automatically.

I read a little bit about the [versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html) but I didn't like the use-latest-versions part of it (it seems way to dangerous).  The Update-properties seemed promising but it upon a second cursory look, it looked like the use-latest-versions plugin packaged slightly different.

Also, I tried just using `${project.version}` but that's basically the same as putting 3.4-SNAPSHOT in as the dependency - it'll error saying it can't release due to snapshots since the version actually hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong, but it seems a little odd to say that they all should have the same version, but different parents . . .

Comment: It has to do with packaging. Project 2 is basically a project that takes our artifacts and bundles them up into our deployables.  Exes, rpms, vms, etc.  I think eventually we want to put them all under the same parent but that's a bigger change than what I can tackle at the moment.

Comment: We have a similar use case, i.e. we have jars and wars that are built, and then a bunch of binary installers and stuff like that.  We too originally tried to have them all have the same version number, because it seemed to make sense that they were all part of the same "product".  We're now moving towards giving each piece it's own versioning to give them more independence.  It's a complicated story . . . and we haven't cleaned it up enough to consider automating releases yet, alas.

Comment: I've tried to improve your title based on my understanding of your question. Please correct it if you think its wrong.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I think that works. Part of this problem has actually been to figure out what to search on.

Answer (score 1):

As you admit, the right answer here is to re-arrange your project to have a common parent. Anything else is just a workaround.

However, it looks to me like [`versions:use-releases`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html) might achieve your goal. You can specify an includes list to ensure only project 1 dependencies are updated.

<strike>If you wanted this to be automatic, you could consider binding this goal to one of the [lifecycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) prior to `compile`.</strike>

**Edit**: sadly this looks like its not possible. At least, that's how I understand by the "*Executes by direct invocation only*" mentioned at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Duncan,  I found this: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/release-process-and-SNAPSHOT-upgrade-td3409242.html  which had some good insight on what is involved.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have the projects configured they are totally independent. You might as well be asking for the version of your log4j dependency to be the same as your current project B version.

While it won't be automatic, you should replace the versions of all references to Project A within Project B to use a property that is defined in the parent pom for Project B. Then, when you release Project A, you only have to change one pom so the `project.a.version` property is now the released version instead of SNAPSHOT. After the release of B you could then change it back to `${project.version}` to keep them in sync.

Comment: Thanks, as is mentioned in the link i responded to Duncan Jones's post, there might be a way to do what you've suggested using the maven invoker plugin.  Otherwise, i'll put a collection of bamboo scripts together to accomplish something similar.